# reference to where the parser is at when calling a rule listener in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, parser-generator

*I'm generating listeners in Python, but any language is ok for answers or comments.*

I need to know if there's **some reference to where** in the parsing tree, or even better, in the **token stream** or in the **source file** the **parser is at** when calling a specific listener method.
I get a context object, which has a reference to the parser itself, I looked for it but don't seem to find any.
This is for debugging only.

`def enterData_stmt(self, ctx:fassParser.Data_stmtContext):`

*I know the parser doesn't traverse the source file but rather the abstract syntax tree, and I could look at it and get where the parser is at, but I'm wondering if I can get a little context for quick debugging without having to do a tree traversal*

Answer (score 0):

Every `ParseRuleContext` object has the fields `start` and `stop`, which contain the first and last token matched by the rule respectively. The token objects have the methods `getLine` and `getCharPositionInLine` to find out the line number and column number where each token starts respectively (there are no methods telling you where a token ends (except as an absolute index - not a line and column number), so if you need that, you'll need to calculate it yourself using the start position and the length).

> I know the pareser doesn't traverse the source file but rather the abstract syntax tree

Of course the parser traverses the source file - how else could it parse it? The parser goes through the source file to generate the (not very abstract) parse tree. If you're using a visitor or `ParseTreeWalker` with a listener, the visitor/listener will then walk the generated parse tree. If you're using `addParseListener`, the listener will be invoked with the partially-constructed tree while the parser is still parsing the file.